# Removing a row from table with two foreign keys entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table which consists of only 2 foreign keys as columns. These keys in the table represent a many to many association between 2 other tables. For example: The table is `RoleGroup`, and the only 2 columns are `GroupId` and `RoleId`, both foreign keys to `Group` and `Role` tables, respectively. The generated EF object from database didn't create the `RoleGroup` object, only navigation properties with the other tables. I can insert data in `RoleGroup` table in EF as follows:

```
Group grp = context.Groups.Where(g => g.Id == 8);
Role role = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Id == '001c');
grp.Roles.Add(role);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now, how do I remove a row within the table `RoleGroup` in EF e.g. remove a group (with `Id = 5`) from a role with Id say `'001b'`?

Comment: Try to update EF and then check  RoleGroup should be there.

Comment: `RoleGroup` table is not generated in EF, so how do I check that in EF?

Comment: Click on `EDMX-> Update model from database- Add` and then click on table.

Comment: I tried that and it's not generated because it's only a table with just 2 foreign keys as columns hence it only automatically created navigation properties.

Comment: Can you show DB structure and EF screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework, like most ORM's abstracts away link tables. Presuming that you've got everything set up correctly you can remove the record by removing the link.

```
Role role = //Whatever Role;
group.Roles.Remove(role);
```